# Statistical test for grouped results without individual data

Tags: statistical-significance, group-differences

I have a dataset containing grouped participant ratings for words. Several groups of participants rated the words, these groups differed in their age and sex. However, I do not have individual ratings, only the grouped responses. I.e. the rows are words and the columns correspond to the participant group(e.g. male 18, female 18, male 20…etc).  The cells contain the average ratings for the corresponding word and participant group.

Originally I sought to do a repeated measures ANOVA with words as the unit of analysis and age and sex as the repeated measures. But this is showing up as significant where it shouldn’t (i.e. significant overlap of standard error bars on figures).

In the absence of individual data - What statistical test could be done to determine the impact of sex and age on word ratings?

Thank you